# xamarin ios uilabel issues

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uilabel

I am quite new to programming, so I am hoping this is a very simple mistake. I have created a `UILabel` in an xamarin ios app using visual studio and I want to update it with new data every 30 seconds. I have gotten it to update, but rather than only the new number in my label, I get the new number on top of my previous number, which after a few times running though, it is unreadable. How do I make it so I only get the new value of my `int` in the `UILabe`?

My code is as follows

```
    int mytest = 0;
    private async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        while (0 == 0)
        {
            mytest++;

            var t1label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 10, 200, 100));
            t1label.Text = mytest.ToString();
            View.Add(t1label);
            t1label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
          await Task.Delay(30000);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue. You must initialize the label before while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You create the entire `UILabel` each time the loop runs. That's why it appears several times on the screen.

Create the label outside the loop and refresh only the `Text` property inside the loop. For example like this:

```
int mytest = 0;
private async Task RefreshAsync()
{
    var t1label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 10, 200, 100));        
    View.Add(t1label);
    t1label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);

    while (true)
    {
        t1label.Text = mytest.ToString();
        mytest++;
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
}
```

Further information:
You are changing the UI by updating the label's `Text` in a different thread. That can cause problems. You should execute UI updating code always on main thread. So it's better to change the line

```
t1label.Text = mytest.ToString();
```

to

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() => t1label.Text = mytest.ToString());
```

Read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Label on each iteration of the loop, and then layering it on top of the existing label.  Instead, you should just create the label once, and only update it's value:

```
int mytest = 0;

// create the label outside of the loop
var t1label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 10, 200, 100));
t1label.Text = mytest.ToString();
View.Add(t1label);
t1label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);

private async Task RefreshAsync()
{
    while (0 == 0)
    {
      mytest++;

      t1label.Text = mytest.ToString();

      await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do as you suggested above, but I get a lot of errors when I do. mainly on var when creating the label. it has the error "The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code" am I missing something simple here? is it possible to create a public label?

Comment: just explicitly declare it as Label instead of using var

Comment: I am hoping this is my final question: how do I add it to the view? view.add(t1label) does not work in this case as it is not in a class. I greatly appreciate your help! the error I get is "The name 'View.add' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: then pass a reference to your view into the method that is doing the update